# Selenium set preference directory

Tags: c#, firefox, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using firefox webdriver. I want to store all the cookies and cache files into a custom directory. But its taking a temp directory instead of my directory . Here is my code:

```
FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile(path, false);
MessageBox.Show(firefoxProfile.ProfileDirectory);     //Its showing blank
driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile);
MessageBox.Show(firefoxProfile.ProfileDirectory);    //Its showing the temp dir
                                                     //not my custom dir
```

How to make it take my directory and store all the cookies and files there ?

Thanks.

EDIT:

I need to make the selenium profile directory fixed (as it is changing all the time). So that I can use previous cookies and cache files. Can you give me any idea or any alternate way to accomplish it ?

Comment: I don't think this is possible (saving the cookies in a specified directory) - you can read about a similar question here : http://groups.google.com/group/selenium-users/browse_thread/thread/bc39b481edfafd1c/b9d225ca36648fbf?lnk=gst&q=firefox+cookie+directory#b9d225ca36648fbf

Answer (score 0):

`FirefoxProfile.ProfileDirectory` refers to a generated profile directory(obviously, available after browser instance creation only).
As per Selenium source code, profile directory is generated as a random directory in temp folder, hence **could not be changed**

```
// creates a random folder name in Path.GetTempPath()
this.profileDir = GenerateProfileDirectoryName();
```

and

```
public string ProfileDirectory
{
    get
    {
        return this.profileDir;
    }
}
```

Whereas the `profileDirectory` you specify during `FirefoxProfile` creation is used to load user.js.

Quote from [mozillaZine](http://kb.mozillazine.org/User.js_file):

> A user.js file is an alternative method of modifying preferences,
>   recommended for advanced users only.

**Upd.**
The only way to solve your issue I could see, besides digging into selenium sources, is changing temp folder location before starting the webdriver to your desired folder and then changing it back to it's original value for current user.

**Upd2.**
Another possible solution(although not tried yet) is specifying `ProfileDirectory` from a previous webdriver run as `profileDirectory` for a new instance of `FirefoxProfile` for another instance of webdriver. Given that all the files from `profileDirectory` are copied to the generated temp folder, that could help you achieve desired functionality.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to using selenium. My problem is - I need to fix the selenium profile directory (as it is changing all the time). So that I can use previous cookies and cache files. Can you give me any idea, how to accomplish it ?

Comment: If you are starting Firefox WebDriver twice, you could get firefoxProfile.ProfileDirectory from the first run and specify it as argument during firefoxProfile profile creation for the second run.

Taking into account, that this folder is copied to the temp, this could work.

Comment: So changing the user.js is the best way to do it ? Could you please send me a sample user.js content which is doing this job. Sorry for asking this. But I could not find any sample which is doing this.

Comment: As you could have read, user.js is meant to modify browser preferences. I doubt it allows modifying cookies.

Answer (score 0):

You could just find the temp file path as you are already then copy your files into this folder with system commands after creating the driver. Then you would have access to them, though this is a little hacky but should work ( unless I've missed something crucial here, which I feel I may have :) )

Answer (score 0):

Is it absolutely necessary for you to use firefox? If you are using IE, won't this be taken care? From selenium jar help contents

> -ensureCleanSession: If the browser does not have user profiles,make
>   sure every new session has no artifacts from previous sessions.  For
>   example, enabling this option will cause all user cookies to be
>   archived before launching IE, and restored after IE is closed.

So, if you **don't** use that option while running tests in IE your cookies will stay. I haven't tried in webdriver, but I have seen the cookie being retained while using Selenium 1.